# Hyperref Error in arxiv submission

Tags: hyperref, arxiv

I'm trying to submit my document to `arxiv`, but it is giving an error (probably related to `hyperref`). My code is available here: https://www.overleaf.com/8195616gtsnqfwfbrct#/28970542/

But the main parts which I think are important are as follows:

I have the following settings in my tex file:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{rerunfilecheck}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
```

And part of the arxiv log file is as follows:

```
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(./IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2007/03/05 V1.7a by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using DVI output.
-- This is a 10 point document.
) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/authblk.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/atveryend.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/uniquecounter.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/bigintcalc.sty)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3dvips.def)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/relsize/relsize.sty)
********************************************************
Package `algorithm2e' Release 5.1 -- october 19 2015 --
- algorithm2e-announce@lirmm.fr mailing list for announcement about releases
- algorithm2e-discussion@lirmm.fr mailing list for discussion about package
subscribe by emailing sympa@lirmm.fr with 'subscribe <list> <firstname name>'
- Author: Christophe Fiorio (christophe.fiorio@umontpellier.fr)
********************************************************
) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def))
(./commondefinitions.tex))
*
! Emergency stop.
<*> settings.tex

No pages of output.
Transcript written on settings.log.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make it a *full* MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible) in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) i.e. the simplest complete document which generates the same error, or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks, I added a link to the minimal form of my code which makes the same error: https://www.overleaf.com/8195616gtsnqfwfbrct#/28970542/

Answer (score 2):

The document from the link in Noshad's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354187/hyperref-error-in-arxiv-submission#comment871132_354187):

```
\pdfoutput=1
\input{settings}
\begin{document} 
\input{title}
\input{abstract}
\input{introduction}
\input{numerical}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{citations.bib}
\end{document}
```

Then the `.log` file of the question gives some clues. It ends with:

```
*
! Emergency stop.
<*> settings.tex

No pages of output.
Transcript written on settings.log.
```

Observations:

- The star means, that TeX expects input, thus it does not have finished the job as in `\end{document}`.
- The job name is `settings`, which is the first input file in the main document that presumably contains the preamble.
- Default driver of `hyperref` is reported as `hdvips`:

  ```
  Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.
  ```

  However, the main file starts with switching into PDF mode:

  ```
  \pdfoutput=1
  ```

  Then, the default driver of `hyperref` is `hpdftex`.

**Conclusion:**

The main TeX file was never executed. Instead, `settings.tex` was used as main document, just the preamble and without the document body.

Comment: I'm still confused! even removing \pdfoutput=1 from the main file gives the same error. What is suggested to correct this behavior?

Comment: @Noshad Your "main" file is never run, only `settings.tex` is fed to LaTeX.

Comment: It still does not say how to keep `\pdfoutput=1` and make sure that `main.tex` is compiled first.